# Why can't I see paths that exist in OSX?

Tags: node.js, macos, osx-mavericks, nodemon

I am a windows developer switching over to OSX. I am very confused though. I am learning node.js and the documentation tells me to add a reference to nodemon at the path...

**/usr/local/bin/nodemon**

However when I am at the terminal and I type **'ls'** I get the following output...

[image]

And that doesn't have a /usr/ folder ... And what is even more confusing is that if I do...

**ls -a**

Then I can see all my hidden folder with a folder in called .npm which seems to have all my modules. In windows this is easy it just installs all npm modules into %AppData%/npm or something but I just don't get it on OSX can somebody enlighten me please?

Comment: The ls is being called in your hime directory. Try 'ls /'

Comment: `ls`without any parameters lists what you have in the **current** directory. On OSX, this current directory should be something like /Users/your_user_name. To see if you have `nodemon`installed where you think it is, use `ls /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Recommended: [CLI crash course](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` lists the directories and files in your *current working directory*.

You can find your current working directory with `pwd` (short for 'print working directory')

You can change your current working directory with the `cd` (change directory) command. In your case, you could run

```
cd /usr/local
ls
```

and it would show you the `bin` directory. Alternatively, you could directly run

```
ls /usr/local
```

As a special extra note, the Terminal Prompt itself actually displays the current working directory (by default). In your case, it shows `~`, which is shorthand for the user profile directory, which the Terminal opens to automatically. It is generally `/Users/<username>`.

Comment: Brandon this is really helpful, thankyou this would have taken me days to figure out!

Comment: Once you know it well, you'll never go back. This is a tutorial that was very helpful to me. [Intro to the Mac OS X Command Line](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line)